# Nivo Slider sliding workaround (not always sliding in one direction)

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

Let me prefix this by saying how much I love this community here at stackoverflow, and its always a great help to browse and as questions here, so thanks a lot!

The problem.
So I have a client that would like a slideshow that can slide the images from the right->to->left if the right navigation arrow is pressed and from left->to->right if the left arrow is pressed.

Currently in the configuration documentation for nivo-slider(its the only one I really ever use) I cant seem to get anything apart from either always sliding right or always sliding left (slideInLeft, slideInRight).

Is there anyway, to for instance, depict which is pressed, and run that animation method instead of the usual one?

Thanks in advance,
Aleski.

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried changing settings.effect on the fly when the prev/next links are changed, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Have you found a work around for this? I'm trying to figure out how to do this as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to "jquery.nivo.slider.js" before comment "// Run effects" after comment and code in "// Custom transition as defined by "data-transition" attribute". This show change current effect if you click on left or right arrow or buttons. For this work you must have imageis in HTML without "data-transition" attribute and default effect you must define in "jquery.nivo.slider.js" under comment "//Default settings" because "data-transition" attribute is prefer. I code it right know for my project.

```
        if(nudge === 'prev'){
            currentEffect = 'slideInLeft';
        } 
        else if (nudge === 'next'){
            currentEffect = 'slideInRight';
        }
        else if (nudge === 'control'){
            currentEffect = 'fade'; /*test*/
        }
```

Comment: I simply dont understand anything in that answer, besides adding the code to the nivo js file. Which effect am i supposed to set as default?

Comment: Default effect is not important with this code I change default effect to another as you want. Without this code you have only same "default" effect on arrows and control.
=> this code on right arrow use "slideInLeft" ; on left arrow "slideInRight" and on navigation button used "fade" effect.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed this question - I answered [Chris's similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353332/how-can-you-change-effect-in-nivo-slider-based-off-of-previous-or-next-slide-key) and this solution should hopefully work for you as well:

Per the [nivo slider documentation](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/advanced-tutorials/setting-custom-transitions-per-slide/) you can change the effect for each slide by adding a custom data attribute onto any or all of the images and it will override nivo's default transition:

```
<img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="" data-transition="slideInLeft" />
```

You can alter this custom data dynamically by setting an event handler on the document body to look for a keypress and then change the attr of all the images using the snippet below:

```
var $body = $("body");
var $images = $("img");

$body.on('keydown', function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left 
     $images.attr("data-transition","slideInLeft");
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
     $images.attr("data-transition","slideInRight");
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix this by putting following code in the `nivoRun` function of the `jQuery.nivo.slider.js` file (just after the currentEffect variable is initialised) :

```
if(settings.effect === 'slideInLeftRight')
{
    if(nudge === 'prev')
    {
        currentEffect = 'slideInRight';
    }
    else
    {
        currentEffect = 'slideInLeft';
    }
};
```

This code creates your own effect called `slideInLeftRight`.

The `slideInLeftRight` effect will use the `slideInRight` effect when the `prev` button is pressed and it will use the `slideInLeft` effect when the `next` button is pressed.

Use the `slideInLeftRight` effect like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'slideInLeftRight',
        ...
    });
});
</script>
```