# How do I give a specific transition effect for nivo slider based off od prev or next arrows?

Tags: javascript, slider, slideshow, nivo-slider

I'm looking into causing a specific transition effect based off of the arrow the user clicks on.

so I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353332/how-can-you-change-effect-in-nivo-slider-based-off-of-previous-or-next-slide-key) and I'm trying to adapt it my way, without success.

So I have those images :

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    <?php   foreach($SlideShowImages as $SlideShowImage){
    ?>
        <img src="<?php echo base_url($SlideShowImage['image_url']);?>" data-thumb="" alt="Image SlideShow"/>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </div>
```

and I would like that, if the user click on that arrow :

> `<a class="nivo-prevNav">Prev</a>`

he has a specific effect, so I tried this :

```
$('.nivo-prevNav').on('click', function(){
       $('#slider img').attr("data-transition","slideInLeft");
  });
```

without success ...

EDIT: Thanks to roine, I've made this function working, but I have one last question, first, when I click on the arrow, it appears to change the transition effect only the second time I click on it. My understanding of that is that the first time I click on the arrow, I apply changes on the picture, and then, the second time, thoses changes are taken in consideration by the process of nivo slider.

So I saw those lines in the nivo slider customisation:

```
beforeChange: function(){}, // Triggers before a slide transition
afterChange: function(){}, // Triggers after a slide transition
```

Maybe I should call the function here ?

Thanks

Comment: data-* attribute should be use as following: $('#slider img').dataset.transition = "slideInLeft"

Comment: erf still no effect, But i think my problem comes from $('.nivo-prevNav').on('click', function(){ since I don't any alert when putting an alert inside the function. Does it look good to you ?

Comment: which version of jquery are you using? on exist since 1.7 try to use live instead of on.$('.nivo-prevNav').live('click', function(){
       $('#slider img').attr("data-transition","slideInLeft");
  });

Comment: great, it is working ! But still, can you give a look to my edit please ? Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution [here](http://www.soslignes-ecrivain-public.fr/Nivo-Slider-playing-with-transitions.html) :

```
// Assigning a Specific Effect to the Prev/Next Buttons
    $('.nivo-prevNav').live('mouseover', function(){
         $('#slider img').attr("data-transition","sliceUpDown");
    });

    $('.nivo-nextNav').live('mouseover', function(){
         $('#slider img').attr("data-transition","sliceUpDownLeft");
    });
```